# How can I use $ and euro buttons

Tags: 11.04, keyboard-layout, acer

I have an Acer Aspire 5930

There are two buttons, which I can't use now: <kbd>$</kbd> and <kbd>€</kbd>

[image]
When I press those buttons *nothing* happens.
How can I use it?

On Windows I can use the program Launch Manager for it (from acer.com)

I tried going to: *System->Preferences->Keyboard->Layots->Keyboard model ->Acer->Acer Laptop*

But that didn't help me.

Comment: Is your local set correctly? I.E. does it recognise your country and language? Look at System menu -> Administration -> Language Support

Comment: @arochester. It was English lang first, now I add русский(eng. Russian, its my language), it not helps, on "Regionalformats" tab My country and language are ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This works with my Acer Aspire 8930g laptop:
>
> Firstly, put in /etc/init.d/local, or whatever startup script your
>   distro uses to run startup commands as root: Code:
>
> ```
>     # dmesg | grep atkbd
>   setkeycodes e033 219    # euro sign
>   setkeycodes e034 239    # dollar sign
> ```
>
> Secondly, execute these commands in your window manager startup
>   (exactly how to do this, differs with every window manager, just to
>   confuse us): Code:
>
> ```
>     xmodmap -e "keycode 244 = dollar"
>     xmodmap -e "keycode 195 = EuroSign"
> ```
>
> In my experimentations, xmodmap can be run "too soon", which prevents
>   it from taking effect! Try adding "sleep 5" before the xmodmap
>   commands, if they don't seem to take effect.
>
> Not sure if this makes a difference, but in xorg.conf I have: Code:
>
> ```
>     Option "XkbModel" "acer_laptop"
> ```

Source: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=203271

Comment: Works with some others keycodes to xmodmap for me. acer_laptop is not important AFAIU

Answer (score 0):

I have a <kbd>4</kbd> key that has both $ and € as meta keys.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> returns $
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> returns €

Comment: I can use shift+4(but not altgr+4) too, But I don't want to have unused keys, if I can use it:)